# Laravel Redirect Error

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, controller, routes

I am having below error while posting any type form for 1 or two seconds on a white screen

> **Redirecting to http://sitename.com/laravel/public/something/something**

then the page redirects sucessfully to my requested page.

which is not good

i have been using the following redirection methods

```
Return Redirect::action('SampleController@somefunction');

Return Redirect::to('something/something');

Return Redirect::route('something');
```

**all the above gives me same error**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually this happens because there is some output *as well as* the redirect, and as such Laravel cannot send an HTTP header in order to redirect the browser (and thus must send a page with some Javascript that does the redirect). That's why you see that page. As for what could be causing it, it's hard to say as it could happen for a variety of reasons. Here are some common causes, though:

- PHP files with whitespace outside of PHP tags that shouldn't have it (classes, etc.), especially true at the beginning and end of a file (if you use the `?>` closing tag at the end of a file). The UTF-8 byte order mark can do this too, though must text editors use UTF-8 without the BOM these days.
- Something in a route filter (before or after) outputting something accidentally
- Some debugging code in `/public/index.php` or whatever that outputs something
- Output buffering somehow turned off on your PHP installation?

Laravel does try to wrap a lot of the execution in output buffering functions to help mitigate the possibility of something being output and messing with its ability to send HTTP headers, but it's not perfect as it's not run right from the absolute beginning.

Comment: I enabled the output buffering  in php.ini file and solved the problem